# GitHub - completely messed up the local files of gitHub in my computer

Tags: git, github

I created a repo in the wrong folder. Meaning the User folder in OS where all the user folders are from pics, videos to documents. So I pushed that all to gitHub without knowing and now I can't create a repo anymore because the files that I work with are in the documents folder, which is inside the User Folder. And it will imply that I'm creating a repo within a repo. So when I go to terminal and I run git status, it shows me this:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 2 and 4 different commits each, respectively.
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    Documents/m3/m3---Best-Game-Ever
#   deleted:    Documents/of_v0072_osx_release/apps/myApps/CCLab_2/cclab_sketch_1/src/Boxes.cpp
#   deleted:    Documents/of_v0072_osx_release/apps/myApps/CCLab_2/cclab_sketch_1/src/Boxes.h
#   deleted:    Documents/of_v0072_osx_release/apps/myApps/ball_bouncing/Ball.cpp
#   deleted:    Documents/of_v0072_osx_release/apps/myApps/ball_bouncing/Ball.h
#   deleted:    Documents/of_v0072_osx_release/apps/myApps/bouncing_ball_classes/src/ball.cpp
#   deleted:    Documents/of_v0072_osx_release/apps/myApps/bouncing_ball_classes/src/ball.h
#   deleted:    Documents/of_v0072_osx_release/apps/myApps/ms_final/src/backGround.cpp
#   deleted:    Documents/of_v0072_osx_release/apps/myApps/ms_final/src/backGround.h
#   deleted:    Documents/of_v0072_osx_release/apps/myApps/ms_final/src/backGround2.cpp
#   deleted:    Documents/of_v0072_osx_release/apps/myApps/ms_final/src/backGround2.h
#   deleted:    Documents/of_v0072_osx_release/apps/myApps/mySketch/src/backGround.cpp
#   deleted:    Documents/of_v0072_osx_release/apps/myApps/mySketch/src/backGround.h
#   deleted:    Documents/of_v0072_osx_release/apps/myApps/mySketch/src/backGround2.cpp
#   deleted:    Documents/of_v0072_osx_release/apps/myApps/mySketch/src/backGround2.h
#   deleted:    README.md
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .Trash/
#   .bash_history
#   .dropbox/
#   .openmdao/
#   .ssh/
#   Documents/2nd_semester/
#   Documents/Arduino/
#   Documents/OpenMDAO/
#   Documents/Personal/
#   Documents/T.A/
#   Documents/gitHub/
#   Documents/mySite/
#   Documents/openFrameworks/
#   Documents/resources/
#   Documents/webcam-pulse-detector-master/
#   Dropbox/
#   Library/
#   Music/
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Needless to say I'm never able to pull anything. It says that everything is up to date. At certain point I had a repo that uploaded those folders without the files to gitHub but I deleted that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First things first:

1. [Delete the Github remote repository](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository) where you uploaded your user folder (you don't want this to be public)
2. [Delete the local repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514054/how-do-i-delete-a-local-repository-in-git) in your user folder.

   ```
   # Be careful, dangerous command, it will erase your repository 
   # Make sure that you run this from the right folder 
   rm -rf .git
   ```

Now, if your local repositories bellow `Documents` start working again **you are done**.
Else, delete and clone each one of them, one by one (of course that this will discard both uncommitted changes and commits that you have not previously pushed).

```
 cd ~/Documents/gitHub/
 # example, and again, be careful, it will erase your entire folder
 rm -rf repositoryA
 git clone git://github.com/myUser/repositoryA.git
 rm -rf repositoryB
 git clone git://github.com/myUser/repositoryB.git 
 # And so on
```

Comment: You sir just saved the day!! So I'm guessing that whenever I want to delete something manual and get rid of it completely I have to re -rf .git

Comment: Removing the `.git` folder will remove the repository :). If you want to get rid of a local repository, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

T delete the `.git` folder in mac os recursively, go to the root folder of your project which contains `.git` folder and use:

```
find . | grep .git | xargs rm -rf
```

to remove its contents and itself.